# SQL UPDATE Error in C# Console Application

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, console, sql-update

Using MS Visual Studio 2010, MS Access 2010(database converted to .mdb) and the program is based on C# Console Application.

I'm new to C# and would like some help on the following:

1.I'm struggling with the following an error:

> Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

I've tried everything but can't seem to find the problem. I've even looked at possible error outside the UPDATE statement but still no luck.
The online help does not seem to help me with my problem and most of the help is regarding a connection with a database server.

```
for (int w = 0; w <= 9; w++)
{
      string PN = names[w];
      int lvl = Convert.ToInt32(level[w]), dmg = Convert.ToInt32(damage[w]), plek = w+1;
      connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source=C:\Users\Home\Desktop\game\game.mdb";
      //Tried this one
      // queryString = "UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName=\""+PN+"\", Level=\"" +lvl+"\", DamageReceived=\""+dmg+"\" WHERE Pos="+ plek;
      //Ended with this one
      queryString = "UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName= @pPN, Level= @plvl, DamageReceived= @pdmg WHERE Pos= @pPlek";

      using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
      using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection))
      {
           try
           {
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pPN", PN);
                 command.Parameters.Add("@plvl", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lvl;
                 command.Parameters.Add("@pdmg", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dmg;
                 command.Parameters.Add("@pPlek", SqlDbType.Int).Value = plek;

                 connection.Open();
                 /*command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PN", PN);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lvl", lvl);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dmg", dmg);
                 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@plek", plek);*/

                 command.ExecuteNonQuery();                                   
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
           }
        }
}

input = Console.ReadLine();
```

[image: The Error that I'm getting]

I would appreciate any help. thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `OleDbCommand` when you debug your code?

Comment: not sure if you refer to `command` or `OleDbCommand` itself but here is both:  `command = UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName= @pPN, Level= @plvl, DamageReceived= @pdmg WHERE Pos= @pPlek`  `OleDbCommand = System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEVEL` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#P) in Access SQL. Try using this instead:

```csharp
queryString = "UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName= @pPN, [Level]= @plvl, DamageReceived= @pdmg WHERE Pos= @pPlek";
```

Also, as noted in another answer, OleDb **ignores** parameter *names* and only pays attention to the order in which they appear in the CommandText, so people usually just use the question mark (`?`) as the parameter placeholder/name, e.g.

```csharp
queryString = "UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName=?, [Level]=?, DamageReceived=? WHERE Pos=?";
// ...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", PN);
command.Parameters.Add("?", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lvl;
command.Parameters.Add("?", SqlDbType.Int).Value = dmg;
command.Parameters.Add("?", SqlDbType.Int).Value = plek;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that *OleDbCommand* doesn't support named parameters. You have to use the question mark ? instead. Try something like:

```
UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName= ?, Level= ?, DamageReceived= ? WHERE Pos= ?
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) you will find the full example.

Comment: Okay I did the following: `queryString = "UPDATE Scores SET PlayerName= ?, Level= ?, DamageReceived= ? WHERE Pos= ?";` and `command.Parameters.Add(PN);
                            command.Parameters.Add(lvl);
                            command.Parameters.Add(dmg);
                            command.Parameters.Add(plek);` But now I get the following **Error**: `The OleDbParameterCollection only accepts non-null OleDbParameter type objects, not String objects.`

Comment: cc: @sgtBlueBird - Actually, OleDb does allow parameters to have names, but it ignores those names and only pays attention to the *position* of the parameters in the CommandText. Hence the use of `?` is *recommended* but is not strictly *required*. Also, the parameter names are not the cause of the error in this case.